# What does 'Dahonesque' mean?

Tags: folding-bicycle

I've seen the term Dahonesque used to refer to some folding bikes, what does it mean? What is the connection between "Dahonesque" bikes and the Dahon company?

Comment: THis might be something for the glossary.

Comment: Thought about that, but it was kind of brand specific and didn't want to make the glossary too long.

Comment: The suffix "-esque", in English, can be added to a "NOUN" to produce a word meaning "NOUN-like".  So it basically means "Dahon-like".  No magic, nothing special.

Comment: Would one ever hear "bromptonesque", "bromptesque", "ternesque", or  "moltonesque" ?

Comment: I don't think so as those bike manufacturers are either too new (Tern) or better about protecting their IP (Brompton). There was a Taiwanese Brompton for a very short while but they're now extinct.

Comment: I think the Dahon is quite singular in having so many clones and copies floating around. Part of it is their much longer lineage - combined with manufacturing in China.

Comment: Google shows 1480 hits for "Dahonesque" (including this answer), 778 for bromptonesque,  zero for bromptesque, zero for ternesque, and zero for moltonesque.  So I guess I should create a "Bromtonesque" answer too! :-)

Comment: @RoboKaren Interestingly enough I get completely different results. Dahonesque comes in at only 57 results, but only actually shows 17 results as many are basically duplicates. Bromptonesque meanwhile comes in at 372 results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dahon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahon) is an American bicycle company founded in 1982 by **Da**vid T. **Hon** (Da Hon). They are famous for their folding bikes, which are manufactured overseas.

Dahon officially markets under its own brand name as well as through affiliated brand names such as Yeah, Biceco, and Novara.

But in the years after the Dahon came out, people noticed that very similar-to-identical folding bikes were being sold under other (often unknown or house) labels. These were often not the newest models, but a generation older and with some changes such as different grips, locking mechanisms, or gearing.

It's unclear whether Dahon officially licenses their older designs to other companies to market under their own names; whether these are "excess" but official frames that have been repurposed or made during a "ghost shift"; total rip-off designs using the original plans; or, simply "inspired" by the Dahon design. Given the variety from perfect-clones to off-copies, most probably all of the above.

Because of the family connection and resemblance to Dahons, these folding bicycles that appear to use the original Dahon designs are called **Dahonesque**.

Note 1: some people also use the term **Dahon-clone** to refer to exact copies.

Note 2: The Tern Company was founded by the wife and son of David Hon (the Dahon founder). The first Terns were definitely Dahonesque, but recent models show considerable genetic drift, perhaps enough to make them their own species.

---

Finally, let's play, Spot the Real Dahon!

[image: Dublin Explorer]
[image: Dahon Curve]
[image: Fnhon VG2018]
[image: Dahon Vigor D9]

From top to bottom: Dublin Explorer (a £99 copy); the real Dahon Curve; the [Fnhon](http://www.bikeforums.net/folding-bikes/956320-what-s-story-behind-fnhon.html) VG2018 - an unlicensed clone; the real Dahon D9.

Comment: The image pair I used (Dublin Explorer versus Dahon Curve) may not be the best examples since the Dublin is a near-copy rather than an exact-copy. Feel free to suggest others.

Comment: Added the Fnhon VG2018, which is about as close to an illegal clone copy as you can get. See the link to bikeforums for the story - "FNHON's CEO Mr Feng is a formal DAHON sales manager.He and his team left DAHON and created new brand FNHON and FSIR. in their early stage they provided DAHON clone and modifying parts mainly for DIYer market.now they also provide original design folders and frames."