# Any idea what this is before I buy it?

Tags: identify-this-bike, folding-bicycle

[image]

I Found this locally. What is it? It is currently for sale for what looks like a good price and it's in pristine condition, no rust - looks like it's never been used!

Do you know what kind of bike (manufacturer, model) is this bicycle?

---

I want a bike I can keep at work and ride into town every now and then for my lunch (flat and about 2 miles/3km). And also to throw in the car for when i am out an about incase i want to ride a short distance rather than walk it. £150 for it in pristine condition seems like a bargain, and my question was more what is the model ?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Be aware that item evaluation or saying how much money something is worth is specifically off-topic for this site. That is because prices quickly change in time and space and depend on many factors that cannot be evaluated without a close inspection.

Comment: It says "Bickerton" on it, and "[Bickerton Portables](https://www.bickertonportables.co.uk/)" is a company that makes folding bikes.  If you can ask how old it is, you can probably look up the model with that information.

Comment: @DavidW Make that an answer, please.  You're 100% right and deserve to earn the rep for that,

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered a few years ago. [Identify this old folding bike that I got from the tip - an early Dahon?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45939/identify-this-old-folding-bike-that-i-got-from-the-tip-an-early-dahon)

It's a rebranded Dahon folder and quite unusual. I leave my previous answer below

---

The history of Bickerton bikes is quite amusing-- you should look it up. They are quite interesting.

The newer model you have here will probably be a better bike than the ''design classic'' original.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an early 1990s-vintage [DAHON](https://eu.dahon.com/) folding bike, branded and resold by [Bickerton](https://www.bickertonportables.co.uk/).  From 1982 through [at least to 1987](https://eu.dahon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1987-Dahon-Folder-Users-Manual.pdf) DAHONs had a brace that ran diagonally up from the top tube hinge to support the head tube about half way up, as seen in this image:

[image: 1980s Bickerton-branded DAHON folding bike in silver, showing the Bickerton branding and the head tube support.]

This image displays the bike in Bickerton (instead of DAHON) branding, which is very close to your picture.

From [1990 on](https://eu.dahon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1990-folders-by-dahon-users-manual.pdf) DAHON removed that brace, and adopted the pattern of fenders (including the molded-in rear reflector) and chainguard that are in your image:

[image: 1991/92 DAHON Classic 3 EP203 with nearly identical styling.]

This image is of a 1991/92 DAHON Classic 3 EP203. As you can see, except for colouring and branding, it is nearly identical to the one in your picture.

(Click images for larger views.)

I have found some photos of Bickerton bikes branded "Californian", but the "Bickerton" company logo on them is different, so I don't know which came first:

[image: Blue Bickerton "Californian" showing construction and geometry almost identical to the above DAHON]

Answer (score -1):

It's a folding bicycle. You can fold it down small(ish) so that it fits inside a car boot or inside a carry bag. At 300 quid in that condition I'd say it's worth it, but I don't know the brand. Folders are usually rather pricey. The question is, do you need it? It's not a good everyday bike, it's a (rather good) stopgap. Do you need to travel by car and then go some distance to where you need to be? Do you commute by train and have to walk the last couple of kilometres or so?